# Coinbase maturity of 100 transactions

Tags: mining-reward, immature-coins

The [protocol rules](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules) state that

> For each input, if the referenced output transaction is coinbase (i.e.
>   only 1 input, with hash=0, n=-1), it must have at least
>   COINBASE_MATURITY (100) confirmations; else reject this transaction

Why should coinbase transactions with less than 100 confirmations be unspendable? What is the point of the rule?

Comment: The answer to this question is the second answer in the above linked question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that if a fork were to occur, some blocks will be orphaned and not have any coins which can be rebroadcast. If a block containing a transaction you send me gets orphaned, I can still get my coins, but if the block you are sending me coins from gets orphaned, I can not rebroadcast since the coinbase no longer exists on the valid chain.

Comment: But the chances of such a massive fork is basically zero.

Comment: You say that now ;)